# Ajax Issue in CI. Getting data but JQuery shows error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I have the following code

```
<?php
$arr=array();
$arr=$this->session->ques;
if(isset($this->session->username))
{
 echo '<div id="instruction">
      Welcome to Exam
     </div>';
 echo '<div id="questdiv">
       Start Now
     </div>';   
}
?>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#questdiv").click(function()
{
    $("#instruction").hide();
    $.ajax({
      type:"post",
      url:"<?php echo base_url();?>"+"candidate/nextques",
      dataType:"json",
      data:{val: <?php echo json_encode($arr);?>},
      success:function(res){
      if(res)
      {
       $("#questdiv").append('<span>'+res[0]['question']);
       $("#questdiv").append('<span>'+res[0]['option1']);
       $("#questdiv").append('<span>'+res[0]['column2']);
       $("#questdiv").append('<span>'+res[0]['column3']);
       $("#questdiv").append('<span>'+res[0]['column4']);
      }
    },
    error: function(res,status,error) {
        var err = res.responseText;
      alert(res.Message);
      alert(status);
      alert(error);
    }
    }); 
  });   
});
</script>
```

In this code, I have two divs. I want that on clicking the div *questdiv*, AJAX should fire, get the values from controller-model and append some children inside the div.

Although data is fetched from the database (as shown by the network debugging), but preview also shows the above two divs due to which I am getting JSON parsing error.

```
[{"sno":"1","examcode":"PHP-101","question":"What is PHP?","image":"1-1.jpg","option1":"scripting language","image1":"1-2.jpg","option2":"programming language","image2":"1-3.jpg","option3":"both","image3":"1-4.jpg","option4":"none","image4":"1-5.jpg","correctans":"d58abf157fec3d16bf921e97966c9e57"}]
Welcome to Exam
Start Now
```

I am not able to figure out why I am getting parsing error when from the controller, I am getting valid JSON data only?

And if *Welcome to Exam*
 and *Start Exam* are creating problems, then how to solve it?

Comment: Don't return *Welcome to Exam* and *Start Now* on the response if you are expecting it to be json.

Comment: Basically you are sending ajax post request to the same page which is producing json plus the divs. 

I suggest you create a separate php file only containing code for generating the json data without any html and then update your jquery ajax post to point to new url.

Comment: @Taplar I have not returned these two things

Comment: @MohsinMehmood This is CodeIgniter. I understand your solution in Core PHP but how can this be done n CI? Everything works from controller only.

Comment: If you are not returning those strings, then what are you showing us in that last code snippet you have with the json followed by those two strings?

Comment: @Taplar It is copied from the network debugging window of chrome browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have separate controller methods, one that renders the page with divs, and one that only returns your json object. They way you are doing it, you won't have a valid json object because the divs are rendering in there as well (because it is essentially re-rendering the page on ajax call).

Example:

```
class Some_controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('someview');
    }

    public function json() {
        $array = array('123', '456');
        echo json_encode($array);
    }

}
```

Someview:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#doAction').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>some_controller/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (res) {
                    console.log(res);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div><a id="doAction" href="javascript:void()">Some div</a></div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanx for the response and it seems meaningful but how can I open one view from two controllers? If i have one controller that generates JSON then from where the second controller be called?

Comment: Hopefully my example clears things up for you. The 2nd controller *method* is only for returning *json* and thus is only accessed by the **ajax** request.

Comment: Oh !!! I checked. I have different controllers but the mistake was that load view line of code was written in json returning controller too. Silly mistake. Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!